# isValidJSONObject not working as expected

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

After testing, I can only get `[NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:]` to return a positive on JSON data that I have already parsed with `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:]`.

According to the [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/isValidJSONObject%3a):

> isValidJSONObject returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given object can be
>   converted to JSON data.

However, despite the fact that the objects I am attempting to convert from JSON to a NSDictionary convert fine, `isValidJSONObject` returns `NO`.

Here is my code:

```
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError * error=[[NSError alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary * dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:data]){
    NSLog(@"data is JSON");
}else{
    NSLog(@"data is not JSON");
}

if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dict]){
    NSLog(@"dict is JSON");
}else{
    NSLog(@"dict is not JSON");
}

NSLog(@"%@",dict);
```

My log contains the following:

```
data is not JSON
dict is JSON
```

and then the output of dict, which at this point is a huge NSMutableDictionary object. No errors are generated when running this code, but `isValidJSONObject` seems to be returning the wrong value when run on `data`.

How can I get `isValidJSONObject` to work as expected?

Comment: This is wasted motion: `dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`

Comment: @Hot Licks how would you suggest I do that?

Comment: ok, i will remove that line. thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`isValidJSONObject` tests if a *JSON object* (a `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`) can be successfully
converted to *JSON data*.

It is not for testing if an `NSData` object contains valid *JSON data*. To test for valid 
JSON data you just call

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data ...]
```

and check if the return value is `nil` or not.

Comment: ah, ok, as usual i was doing it wrong! :) thanks for the response.

Comment: I tried this, but JSONObjectWithData crashes if data is not a valid json.

Comment: @LuisEspinoza: In my experience, JSONObjectWithData returns nil (and sets the error parameter) if the data is not valid JSON.

Comment: What I found is that if you pass an invalid JSON to *NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData*, it would initiate the object with the only valid data that exists in the JSON while the invalid data will be left out.