# Make valid JSON object from invalid JSON object in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsjsonserialization

I have an NSData object, `_responseData`, which returns `NO` on `[NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:_responseData]`.

Is there a way to retrieve valid JSON objects from this `_responseData`?

My `JSON`: [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jGTSUefP)

Comment: Depends on what's wrong.  You need to dump the string, run it through an online JSON parser, and figure out what the hangup is.

Comment: I think hangup is due to presence of objects other than `NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull` though chrome is able to parse the JSON very easily.

Comment: Provide a NSError pointer, then NSLog the error - it should help you and us.

Comment: What does your JSON data actually look like? Post it. Also, valid JSON can only contain the following types: strings, null, numbers, arrays, and maps (objects). Anything else is not actually JSON.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar: Please read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17150095/1187415) to the "possible duplicate". Your JSON is valid. Your method of testing the validity is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR Working Now. :D

Comment: **WE NEED MORE INFORMATION!!**  The JSON itself (or part of it) the error messages from isValidJSONObject, et al.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a valid JSON example:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

Here is an invalid JSON example:

```
jwnfjnng;ner;ng;ne;g n;e;yjq5 jqij43'igjij4;5jg g'45wg'ok'\ekp4t6
```

Now you are asking if you can make from invalid to a valid one. Do you realize now what are you asking?

- if you manually check the JSON and you figure out what is missing maybe 1 or 2 letters closing braces, than maybe

Comment: No my JSON is valid for browser but not for Objective-C. It might have objects other than `NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull`. Is there any way I could skip those objects and serialize rest of the JSON?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar better Paste here the JSON, better Edit your question and paste there